# Direct communication between an USB flash drive and a PC over another PC

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

Assume that an usb flash drive is plugged in a pc and a usb cable is plugged in the same pc.

Is it possible to create something like a direct connection between the end of the usb cable and the usb flash drive? So that when I plug in the usb cable into **another** pc, I will get straight access to the usb flash memory as if I would plug in the usb flash drive directly into the **other** pc.

If it possible, is there already software which makes this scenario possible?

Comment: Without knowing your specific intended use case, it seems like your best option is to 'share' the flash device over the network to the 2nd PC / device. How to do that depends on the OSes involved - could be an NFS or Samba share, or countless other options. You will get full access to the filesystem on the flash drive, but you won't get 'raw' access which would allow things like using 'dd' to copy an image to it, or modifying it's partition table, etc.

Comment: Getting "raw" access to the usb flash drive is exactly what I looked for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, then **no, this is not possible, at least not with standard USB.** It *might* be possible with non-standards-conformant equipment, however, but such equipment would come with its own problems.

Basically, [USB is an asymmetrical topology design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#System_design), where the controller (master) forms the root of a tree branching out toward peripheral devices (slaves) via hubs.

For USB to work, it needs both the controller (host) and one or more peripheral devices.

The closest to what you are trying to do would seem to be [USB On-The-Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go), which basically allows a device to act as *either* a master *or* a slave device. But that requires specific support, and presupposes the *non-existence* of a master on the bus. There can only ever be one master on a USB bus, and your PC is going to act as the master, so you can't add another, so an On-The-Go capable device would assume the role of slave. (And that is, of course, ignoring the fact that your USB memory stick is highly unlikely to be On-The-Go compliant.)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to share it as a USB device you can do so over the network. I do this using an application called [USB/IP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/usbip/).  This runs on Windows (the OS isn't identified in the question).

Not sure how well it works with a flash drive but I'm currently using it to share my scanner. Both machines will see it as a local USB device.